# Drupal 7 - How to get Twitter module to post on Node update

Tags: 7, social-network

I'm using the [Twitter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) and have configured all how I wanted. At the moment when I create a post, a Twit is automatically created and submitted to Twitter. All working as expected.

The problem I'm having whenever I update the post, the update doesn't get posted to Twitter.

In the settings (pic attached), I'm trying to tick the box "Post to Twitter on node update" but every time I his "Save" the tick box get "unticked" and the setting doesn't seem to save.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know why is this happening? Is it a bug in the module?

Thanks